# tidyverse: How do I pivot_wide with multiple columns

Tags: r, tidyr

I have data that looks like this:

```
Subject  Visit  Test   Value  
   1       1      1     100  
   1       2      1      75  
   1       3      1     110  
   1       1      2      12  
   1       2      2      11  
   1       3      2       9  
   2       1      1      125  
   2       2      1      128
```

....

I want it to look like

```
Subject      Visit      Test1      Test2   
   1           1         100          12      
   1           2          75          11  
   1           3         110           9  
   2           1         125          15  
   2           2         128          13
```

I want to keep the Subject and Visit and pivot Test and Value using `pivot_wide`.

Comment: pivot_wider(data = DF, names_from = Test, values_from = Value,  names_prefix = "Test")

Answer (score 5):

```r
df <- read.table(text="Subject  Visit  Test   Value  
1       1      1     100  
1       2      1      75  
1       3      1     110  
1       1      2      12  
1       2      2      11  
1       3      2       9  
2       1      1      125  
2       2      1      128", strin=F,h=T)

library(tidyr)
pivot_wider(data = df, names_from = Test, values_from = Value, names_prefix = "Test")
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   Subject Visit Test1 Test2
#>     <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1       1     1   100    12
#> 2       1     2    75    11
#> 3       1     3   110     9
#> 4       2     1   125    NA
#> 5       2     2   128    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>